# AWS-BOTO security group error

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, boto, botocore

I have the following code to spin up new instances:

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1", security_token = "xx", aws_access_key_id= "xx",  aws_secret_access_key= "xx")


security_groups = conn.get_all_security_groups()
for security_group in security_groups:
    if str(security_group)[14:] == "xx":
        conn.run_instances(
                'ami-da2cd5b2',
                key_name='fornax_keypair',
                instance_type='c1.xlarge',
                security_groups=security_group)
    else:
        continue
```

It finds the security group and then gives the error :

```
TypeError: 'SecurityGroup' object is not iterable
```

If I change it to str(security_group), it then gives the error:

```
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidGroup.NotFound</Code><Message>The security groups 'f', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'n', 'o', 'j', '.', 'i', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'p', '
:', 'y' do not exist</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>c96afd3c-de3f-4441-be65-c6a85fbe7868</RequestID></Response>
```

**Also how do I attach the connection to an already established vpc connection and subnet ?**

Answer (score 1):

The `security_groups` parameter to `run_instances` is supposed to be list of security group names.  You are passing a scalar string value.  Try this instead:

```
conn.run_instances(
    'ami-da2cd5b2',
    key_name='fornax_keypair,
    instance_type='c1.xlarge',
    security_groups=[security_group])
```

Comment: could you answer the last part of the question in bold as well ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking how you can launch an EC2 instance in an existing VPC subnet?